# Converting String to Array in Swift: Time Complexity

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

What's the time complexity of converting a String into an Array in Swift, aka: Array("abc").
Is it O(n) or Swift uses some type of internal mechanism to optimize it as String conforms to Sequence protocol.

Comment: I would assume at least `O(n)`, given that Strings contain glyphs composed of one or more Unicode scalar values.

Answer (score 2):

You're right to think about this in terms of the [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) protocol. But `Sequence` is actually very simple in terms of requirements, and doesn't offer a way to do better than O(n) — the iterator mechanism is described in [IteratorProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol)'s documentation.

The key pieces of source, to see this in action, are found here:

1. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift

```swift
  @inlinable
  public init<S: Sequence>(_ s: S) where S.Element == Element {
    self = Array(
      _buffer: _Buffer(
        _buffer: s._copyToContiguousArray()._buffer,
        shiftedToStartIndex: 0))
  }
```

2. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift (for `_copyToContiguousArray`)

```swift
  // Add elements up to the initial capacity without checking for regrowth.
  for _ in 0..<initialCapacity {
    builder.addWithExistingCapacity(iterator.next()!)
  }

  // Add remaining elements, if any.
  while let element = iterator.next() {
    builder.add(element)
  }
```